# How to process an image from another domain in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, image, http, same-origin-policy

Is there any good way to drag and drop an image form a web page in another domain into my web page and then do some processing on the data?

I have tried a variety of methods, but every method I try seems to run into cross-origin related restrictions.

I can understand say, not running scripts from foreign servers.

But given the following I don't see how inspecting the image data poses any additional security concern.

- The image is publicly available without any credentials.
- The user can already see the image on the original site.
- The user can already right click and save the image if they want, and after saving it, drop it into my web page and do the same processing.  I just want to save them the step.
- If I want to load the image into my web page and then draw it there, the browser displays the foreign image on my web page.
- If I wanted to show the user an altered version of the image, I could still easily do so by just overlaying another transparent canvas on top of it, and drawing on that.
- The fact that the browser won't let someone process the foreign image, doesn't stop someone from making a desktop application that could pull the image from the same URLs and do whatever they want with it.

So if I can already do all those things, how is it a security concern for my script to read the color data from the image?  What bad things can possibly happen if I find out the color of a pixel at coordinate (55, 73) is red?  What possible security attacks could result?

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think there is a way to do it with javascript.

On this point:

> > The user can already right click and save the image if they want, and after saving it, drop it into my web page and do the same processing. I just want to save them the step.

you could do automatically download that image to your server and process the image on it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I had considered downloading the image to my server by creating an dummy anchor <A> tag, and then loading it back into the page from its new location.  I was hoping to avoid storing any user data whatsoever, but maybe it can't be helped.  If I take this approach, I then have a new problem of deleting the old files (which I also apparently cant do directly from JavaScript).

Answer (score 0):

Create a dropzone element (I used a  element but you can create a different element):

```
<main></main>
<script>
  const dropzone = document.querySelector('main');
</script>
```

Give the dropzone a dashed border style:

```
<style>
  main {
    border: 1px border lightgray;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
  }
</style>
```

Highlight the dropzone when the dragenter event is fired (image is dragged over the dropzone):

```
<style>
  .active {
    border: 1px dashed black;
  }
</style>

<script>
  // ...
  dropzone.addEventListener('dragenter', event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    dropzone.classList.add('active');
  });
```

`event.preventDefault() is necessary or else the image will be opened from your local file explorer`.

Remove the dropzone highlight when the dragleave event is fired (image is no longer dragged over the dropzone):

```
<script>
  // ...
  dropzone.addEventListener('dragleave', event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    dropzone.classList.remove('active');
  });
</script>
```

It’s necessary to handle the dragover event before drop happens:

```
<script>
  // ...
  dropzone.addEventListener('dragover', event => {
    event.preventDefault();
  });
</script>
```

Now handle the drop event (when the image is released inside the dropzone):

```
<script>
  // ...
  dropzone.addEventListener('drop', event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    dropzone.classList.remove('active');

    const file = event.dataTransfer.files[0];
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);

    reader.addEventListener('loadend', () => {
      const img = document.createElement('img');
      img.src = reader.result;
      dropzone.append(img);
    });
  });
</script>
```